# Given $N$ elements, what is the probability of $4$ malfunctioning?

Tags: probability

I have $100$ elements.
Any element could malfunction with a probability of $0.04$.

a) What is the probability that exactly $4$ elements malfunction?

b) What is the probability that more than $3$ malfunction?

So, given that only $4$ must malfunction, and the others must not, I came up with this for

a) $0.04^4 \cdot 0.96^{96}$

Now, I was about to use the same process for part b), but that would lead to endless calculations.

Please let me know if a) is wrong (which it probably is), and how should I deal with part b), thank you very much!

An update if anyone ever sees this in the future:

a) I think the answer could be $0.04^4 \cdot 0.96^{96} \cdot C_{100}^4 $, which is taking the probability of four breaking, and others not, and multiplying it by all the possible combinations of four of elements.(something called "binomial approximation" gave me a pretty close answer to the one above)

Comment: Your answer for (a) is the probability the first four malfunction but the next $96$  do not. There are many more possible patterns of *which* four out of $100$ malfunction

Comment: For (b) it is worth finding the probability that exactly $0$, $1$, $2$ or $3$ malfunction

Comment: I had no idea how would I go about expressing all the possible patterns, and a probability table thing for b) is something I can definitely do, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), you only specified a specific order. You need to account for the number of combinations in which 4 can malfunction from a group of $100$, i.e. $_{100}C_4$  (or $100$ choose $4$) times that probability you gave.

On an intuitive level, this makes sense: the probability you gave is about $(5 \times 10^{-6}\%)$. Accounting for the combinations as I did, you get closer to $20\%$. Think of it this way: if you have a 4% failure rate, you'd expect 4 in 100 to fail pretty often, no? Certainly not on the order of one in a million.

---

For (b), one thing you could do would be to, instead, find the probability that 0, 1, 2, and 3 malfunction. This is essentially the opposite of what you're to calculate, i.e. this means

$$P(4,  \; 5,  \; ...,  \; 100 \;  failures) = 1 - P(0, \;  1, \; 2,  \; 3\; failures)$$

Generally, this is stated as

$$P(event \; occurs) = 1 - P(event  \; doesn't  \; occur)$$

I feel there *may* be an alternative method as well but in your case this at least isn't much computation.

Comment: In part (b), we want to calculate the probability that *more than* $3$ malfunction.

Comment: My bad, I'll correct that real quick.